# Profiling android app advanced profiling disabled non gradle app

Tags: android, android-studio, profiling

I have an android app that I build using Android.mk file (non-gradle). I want to profile it using android studio. When I profile the app I get

> Advanced profiling is unavailable for the selected process

Since I do not build the app using android studio, answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50813715/android-profiling-is-unavailable-for-the-selected-process-but-advanced-profilin) do not help.

I have added the below to manifest file

> android:debuggable="true"

and the below to android.mk file

> APP_OPTIM := debug

after following [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-build#debuggable-versus-release-builds)

The app size increases which indicates debugging information has been inserted but still on profiling in android studio I get advanced profiling unavailable error.

I am able to profile the application but most of the advanced features are not available due to this.